# Problem with google cloud text to speech using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, text, speech, ssml

Here are four versions of input texts to [google cloud text to speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech):

Version 1 (This one works fine)

```
<speak version="1.1"        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis                  http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd"        xml:lang="en-GB">

The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.

How kind of you to let me come.

</speak>
```

Version 2: Same as Version 1 except trying to insert external audio.
It results in an error

```
<speak version="1.1"        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis                  http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd"        xml:lang="en-GB">

The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.
<audio src="uhm_male.mp3" />
How kind of you to let me come.

</speak>
```

Version 3: Same as version 2 but with simpler form of

```
<speak>

The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.
<audio src="uhm_male.mp3" />
How kind of you to let me come.

</speak>
```

Results in same error as version 3

And, finally, same as version 3 but excluding audio.
This again, works fine

Here is the python code:

```
import os
from google.cloud import texttospeech_v1

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] =\
 'not_my_real_credentials.json'


def getText(infile_name):
    with open(infile_name, 'r') as fobj:
        intext = fobj.read()
    return intext    

def setVoice(language_code, name, ssml_gender):
    theVoice = tts.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code=language_code,
        name=name,
        ssml_gender=ssml_gender
    )
    return theVoice

def doAudioConfig(speaking_rate, pitch, volume_gain_db):
    audioConfig = tts.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding = tts.AudioEncoding.MP3,
        speaking_rate = speaking_rate,
        pitch = pitch,
        volume_gain_db = volume_gain_db
    )
    return audioConfig

#We try each of these in turn:

#This one works fine
infile_name = './texts/test1.txt'

#This one gives an error message
#infile_name = './texts/test2.txt'

#This one gives same error message as prev
#infile_name = './texts/test3.txt'

#This one works fine
infile_name = './texts/test4.txt'

outfile_name = './audio/audioOutput.mp3'

tts = texttospeech_v1
client = tts.TextToSpeechClient()
language_code = "en-GB"
name = "en-GB-Wavenet-F"
ssml_gender = "FEMALE"
pitch = -8.0
speaking_rate = 0.9
volume_gain_db = 0

intext = getText(infile_name)
print(f'\n{intext}\n')

theVoice = setVoice(language_code, name, ssml_gender)
audioConfig = doAudioConfig(speaking_rate, pitch, volume_gain_db)
synthesis_input = tts.SynthesisInput(ssml=intext)

response = client.synthesize_speech(
input=synthesis_input, voice=theVoice, audio_config=audioConfig)

with open(outfile_name, 'wb') as output1:
    output1.write(response.audio_content)
```

And here is the error thrown by version 2 of the text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 66, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INTERNAL
        details = "Internal error encountered."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1681519238.596000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.70.170:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1075,"grpc_message":"Internal error encountered.","grpc_status":13}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\_new\ttsgcp2\insertAudio.py", line 62, in <module>
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\texttospeech_v1\services\text_to_speech\client.py", line 497, in synthesize_speech
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 68, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered.
```

Using ".wav" and ".ogg" files results in the same error.

Also tried importing "texttospeech" instead of "texttospeech_v1" Same outcomes.

The external audio I'm trying to import sounds fine on all audio players I've tried. It's just an "uhm" sound. Very short. Duration 0.302 seconds

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is because it supports only remote URLs for the `<audio>` tag, just host your audio file on a publicly accessible server and it will work. it must look like the code below, (replace the url with yours)

```
<speak version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd" xml:lang="en-GB">

The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.
<audio src="https://example.com/your_remote_folder/uhm_male.mp3" />
How kind of you to let me come.

</speak>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks but still does not work. My remote file = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sn_lQ5tLS1suzLKPxh1t2HRoA9KJzQ5k

Also had checked with https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/

Their examples had local files

Comment: Error message starts: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 66, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "D:\py\_new\envo\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status...